# Insufficient Privileges while adding field to a custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, insufficient-privileges

My user is with System Administrator profile in the Org

I am trying to add a field to a custom object but getting **Insufficient Privileges** error. Like this:

[image]

System Administrator has Administrative Permission to Customise Application enabled.

System Administrator has all permission on that particular custom object. See below:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: Check the system administrator profile, there is a setting for “create, edit and delete custom fields” and I think you may also need “customise application”. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kB9BIAU

Comment: I am not able to find **create, edit and delete custom fields** in the System Administrator profile.
System Administrator has Customise Application permission.
System Administrator has all permission on that particular custom object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to `Salesforce Classic`.

Now I am able to create the field in the object.

Although it is strange as the object is the same, the user is the same and profile on the user is the same as in *Lightning Experience*.

Answer (score 0):

I was sick of this happening to me and I believe I've discovered the issue, at least for me:

Don't use bookmarks to a custom object's Object Manager page using the custom object's API name. You MUST use the custom object's ID to avoid this insufficient privileges error.

BAD: https://custom-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Custom_Object__c/Details/view

GOOD: https://custom-domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/01Xx000000xxxxx/Details/view

Even though standard objects use a link like this - ...force.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Account/Details - you can't do the same thing with custom objects.

It's misleading because the Object Manager will still allow you to do plenty of things when using the API name in the URL. For example, you can edit an existing field, but you can't add a new one.